# Slideshow stopped working console shows no related errors? But this one unrelated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Here is the error that shows `"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tjq("#price-range").data('url-noprice').replace')"`

That has nothing to do with the slideshow that I can think of?  If you look at the page source you can see the images are there, but the photos tab at the top no longer expands and shows the slide images.

**Example bag:**

http://www.foreversummer.net/accommodation/villas-pappagallo-3/?adults=1&kids=0&rooms=1&date_from&date_to&child_ages%5B0%5D=0

Here is the part of the script that it is having an issue with.

```
if (tjq(".filters-container").length > 0) {
    // price range
    var price_slide_min_val = 0;
    var price_slide_step = tjq("#price-range").data('slide-step');
    var price_slide_last_val = tjq("#price-range").data('slide-last-val');
    var price_slide_max_val = price_slide_last_val + price_slide_step;

    var def_currency = tjq("#price-range").data('def-currency');
    var min_price = tjq("#price-range").data('min-price');
    var max_price = tjq("#price-range").data('max-price');
    if (max_price == "no_max") { max_price = price_slide_max_val; }
    var url_noprice = tjq("#price-range").data('url-noprice').replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    if ((min_price != 0) || (max_price != price_slide_max_val)) {
        tjq('#price-filter').collapse('show');
        tjq('a[href="#price-filter"]').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, if you spot something I have missed.  This one has me stumped.  Could this issue be causing the rest of the query to malfunction?

Comment: `tjq("#price-range")` is selecting elements with the ID of price-range. It doesn't look like you have any elements with that ID on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the URL you added and saw the aforementioned js code.

It seems that you're looking for a dom element with the id "price-range", but it does not exist in your document dom. The element itself is missing.

The following line:

```
var url_noprice = tjq("#price-range").data('url-noprice').replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
```

raises an error because the script is trying to use the method "replace" on 
an undefined object. Step by step:

1. `tjq("#price-range")` → returns an empty array of objects
2. `data('url-noprice')` → is executed on each of the objects in the empty object array and returns `'undefined'`
3. `.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')` → is executed on `'undefined'`

Comment: Thank you for replying.  In our opinion, do you think it could cause the slideshow an inquire button to stop working?  Nothing has been changed but they both stopped working at the same time.  Basically out of nowhere.

Comment: If the inquire button onclick function needs the price-range element to work then yeah. Practically, you can go deeper into the slideshow plugin code and try to understand whats the problem there. You can also try to replace it with another plugin. Another option is to try and revert to an older version of this page and try to see what changes have been made.. one or more of these changes must have caused the deletion of the element.